# how to implement an object[] where as top object is always the latest?

Tags: c#, arrays, xna

I'm writing an app where by i would like to implement an object array which will periodically have a new item added.

i would always like to know which the last object added was and was considering placing that object at position 0. (thus pushing each item down one index to a maximum of 130 items)

this is fairly easy to implement using a List  using

```
items.Insert(0,new item());
items.RemoveAt(130);
```

which will then push each item down automatically and remove the item at 130 yet this is not so simple with an array

my initial thoughts where somewhere along the line of

```
for(int i = 129; i>0;i--)
{
 items[i] = items[i-1]; 
}
items[0] = new item();
```

this then allows me simple access to the latest item (via index[0]), and each preceding item in order of creation (1 -> 129);

now in itself this is fairly simple i was wondering however if there were any other ways of performing this.

EDIT: thanks for the quick replies,

i have performed some testing on this (using 1 million iterations)
it would seem that the queue method is the quickest here but only marginally 
then the list 
then the array which took some 50% longer to process 1 million items

i think i'll explore the <strike>queue</strike> Stack option

thanks again;

Comment: Why do you want to use an array for this?

Comment: Potentially useful Queue implementation based on an array here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Collections-Data-Structure/Implementsthequeuedatatypeusinganarray.htm

Comment: what you describe sounds a lot like a queue. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i would always like to know which the last object added was and was
>   considering placing that object at position 0. (thus pushing each item
>   down one index to a maximum of 130 items)
>   ...
>   now in itself this is fairly simple i was wondering however if there
>   were any other ways of performing this.

Yes, there is a simpler way of performing this by using an already builded structure which is the [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) (First Input First Output). You mainly need three methods which are:

- [`Enqueue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.enqueue.aspx) adds an object to the end of the *queue*.
- [`Dequeue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.dequeue.aspx) returns the object at the beginning of the *queue* **removing it**.
- [`Peek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.peek.aspx) returns the object at the beginning of the *queue* **without removing it**.

Comment: As far as I understand OP seems to be looking for a Stack (FiLo) rather than a Queue (FiFo)

Comment: Indeed i think you may be correct a Stack would be much better suited

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but in some points the question was really unclear. However, it doesn't matter, if you need [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/collection/csharp-collection-tutorial.htm) is a list of collections. Choose what you think is more suitable. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is unnecessary, Array.Insert will "shift down" the elements for you.

But if you really want to always add new elements at the beginning, a LinkedList will be better for performance reasons because it doesn't need to shift elements regardless of where you insert an element.

Answer (score -1):

I think that would be about as simple as you can make it. Personally I would make it a generic extension method.

```
public static void Insert<T>(this T[] array, int position, T item)
{
    for ( int i = array.Length-1; i > position; i-- )
        array[i] = array[i-1];

    array[position] = item;
}
```

So you can use it like

```
string[] lolCats = { "ceiling cat", "invisible bike cat", "lime cat" };

lolCats.Insert(0, "monorailcat");
```